# Magento Cart Buttons not working Update, Remove buttons do nothing when clicked

Tags: php, magento, cart

7.0.2 installation which has recently started having problems on the cart page. I have the remove item links which all look correct however when clicking the link it just doesn't trigger anything and stays on same page. If I copy and paste the contents of the remove item button's a tags href attribute value and view it in browser however this does as expects and loads the new cart page minus the item removed.

I have tried modifiying the template a href value to include the form key and made sure all is correct but the link works anyway so i'm thinking it's something else stopping the link from triggering rather than an issue with the link, however all other links and buttons on page are fine and are no console errors its just as soon as the link is set to /checkout/cart/delete/id or similar it does nothing, set to test and it will go to a not found page as expected. Anyone experienced anything similar to this?

Comment: What does your console say?  I am assuming JavaScript is broken after the upgrade ..

Comment: there wasn't any. To be honest i changed them to javascript links and they worked, a bit hacky and slower what so ever